# Bin rows by time with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So this may seem like a simple question, but every question I've checked isn't exactly approaching the problem in the same way I am.

I'm trying to bin the timestamps of a dataframe into specific buckets. I want to be able to count every minute of a dataframe starting from the first row until the last. I then want to turn that counted minute into a bucket (starting from 1 going to n). I then want to count every row what second it was for the timestamp of that row until the end of the bin.

Here is an example of what I want it to look like:

| time_bin | seconds_in_bin | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-05-05 22:12:59 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-05-05 22:13:00 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-05-05 22:13:01 |
| 1 | 4 | 2022-05-05 22:13:02 |

I'm currently working in python and am trying to do this in pandas with my data. I feel like this problem is much easier than I think it is and I'm just not thinking of the right solution, but some help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question/logic are unclear. What exactly is the input and output? How do you define the bins?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I quite get what you are going for here but wouldn't this be equivalent to getting the rank of seconds?

As far as I understand it, binning has to do with putting together an interval (fixed or not) and counting the number of items in it. If you could please elaborate on this I'll do my best to help with a more plausible answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe binning is the wrong word for it. I'm basically trying to rand the data I have by time intervals of a minute and a second. So for a row of timestamps at a 60 second interval, each timestamp would be part of the first minute (minute 1) and have a second in that bucket (row 1 = second 1).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
string = '''2022-05-05 22:12:59
2022-05-05 22:13:00
2022-05-05 22:13:01
2022-05-05 22:13:02
2022-05-05 22:14:59'''
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': string.split('\n')})
df['s'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.second
df['m'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.minute
df['g'] = (df['s'].diff()+df['m'].diff()*60).fillna(method='bfill').diff().clip(upper=1).fillna(method='bfill')+1
df['count'] = df.groupby('g')['g'].cumsum()/df['g']
df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks keramat! This 100% solves the problem, I'm going to go test it now.

Comment: You're welcome. If there is a problem let me now otherwise please tick the answer as accepted.